# Equivalent of NOT In or IN in Excel like in SQL, I don't want use vlookup or match

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, notin

So I have two sets of data (from two different Excel files), the first column of each Excel file are all same type of data, numbers.

I want to use something equivalent of `IN` or `NOT IN` in SQL in Excel, since I don't think I want to use `match` or `vlookup`. I just want to know if the data in first Excel file (rows that belong to the first column) are in the first column of second Excel file.

Then I want to return possibly as true or false (not sure even I need that).

What is the best way to accomplish in Excel? Should I use `VLOOKup` since I'm comparing two different Excel files. And if I just copy the first row from second Excel file and put in first Excel file, is there something I can use equivalent of `IN` or `NOT IN`?

Iferror or match?

Comment: Yes, use MATCH: for `In` use `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,[yourOtherFile]Sheet1!A:A,0))` and for `Not In` use `=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,[yourOtherFile]Sheet1!A:A,0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner hey thanks, FYI each row in the first column of two excels files are unique, so that's why I want to use something like NOT in of SQL in excel. Can you please write an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `IN` we use:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,[yourOtherFile]Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

Then for `Not In`:

```
=ISERROR(MATCH(A1,[yourOtherFile]Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNTIF` combined with an `IF` statement to confirm the count is greater than zero.

```
=COUNTIF(Dataset_sheet!A:A,A1) > 0, "Yes", "No")
```

[image]

Comment: One note for future users, this work well with smaller (<10,000) datasets.  But if the data set is much larger it will be slow, may error, or even crash Excel.  All the `*IF` formula are very costly.

Comment: It's giving me error when I run this, I copied the first row of second excel file into the same sheet of first excel.